# Error updating Timestamp column in Slick 3.x

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

Given these two classes:

```
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import akka.actor.Actor
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Success
import scala.util.Failure
import java.time.LocalDateTime 
import java.sql.Timestamp


class OlapDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[Olap](tag, "olap_queries") {

  def sk = column[Int]("sk", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def descrip = column[Option[String]]("descrip")
  def notes = column[Option[String]]("notes")
  def mdx = column[String]("mdx")
  def folderSk = column[Int]("folder_sk")
  def lastUpdateUser = column[Option[String]]("last_upd_user")
  def lastUpdateTS = column[Option[LocalDateTime]]("last_upd_ts")(localDateTimeColumnType)
  def version = column[Int]("version")

  def * = (sk, name, descrip, notes, mdx, folderSk, lastUpdateUser, lastUpdateTS, version )
     <>  ((Olap.apply _).tupled, Olap.unapply)
}


implicit val localDateTimeColumnType = 
             MappedColumnType.base[Option[LocalDateTime], Timestamp](
     {
        case Some(localDateTime) => Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime)
        case None => null
     },{
        ts => if (ts != null) Some(ts.toLocalDateTime) else None
     }
  )


case class Olap ( sk: Int, 
                  name: String, 
                  descrip: Option[String], 
                  notes: Option[String], 
                  mdx: String,
                  folderSk: Int,
                  lastUpdateUser: Option[String],
                  lastUpdateTS: Option[LocalDateTime],
                  version: Int)
```

Function `localDateTimeColumnType` works fine when inserting/updating the whole record.

However when trying to update only three columns, I get a compilation error.

This compiles:

```
 val olaps = TableQuery[OlapDB]
 val updateAction = olaps.filter(_.sk === req.sk).map(o => (o.name, o.lastUpdateUser)).update(("my name"), Some("user1"))                
 val future = db.run(updateAction)
```

This doesn't compile:

```
 val olaps = TableQuery[OlapDB]
 val updateAction = olaps.filter(_.sk === req.sk).map(o => (o.name, o.lastUpdateUser, o.lastUpdateTS)).update(("my name"), Some("user1"), Some(LocalDateTime.now()))                
 val future = db.run(updateAction)
```

Note that the only difference is the timestamp column.

This is the error:

> ◾No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given
> types. Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your *
> projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala
> List). Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel Source type:
> (slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[String]],
> slick.lifted.Rep[Option[java.time.LocalDateTime]]) Unpacked type: T
> Packed type: G
>
> ◾not enough arguments for method map: (implicit shape:
> slick.lifted.Shape[_ <: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel,
> (slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[Option[String]],
> slick.lifted.Rep[Option[java.time.LocalDateTime]]), T,
> G])slick.lifted.Query[G,T,Seq]. Unspecified value parameter shape.

Comment: Could you edit your post and show what imports are you using?

Comment: What version of Scala and Slick are you using? The code you've provided compiles without any error on Scala 2.11.8 and Slick 3.1.1.

Comment: I use Slick 3.1.0, I'll try with 3.1.1

Comment: I upgraded to 3.1.1 and get the same error, any ideas? I'm using Scala 2.11.7, not sure that's the problem.

Comment: don't spend more time on this, I can live without updating the timestamp